# Can I make my sprite design very similar to Pokémon's sprite design?

Tags: graphics, legal

I'm making a 2d RPG and I'm having trouble designing a sprite, so I downloaded an image of Pokémon Leaf Green's player sprite and copied how it looked. I didn't copy it completely, only how it looks. Here's the image:

[image]

Can I get sued for this? the gameplay and mechanics are far from Pokémon's mechanics, the only problem is the sprite of the characters. Can I get into trouble because the character sprite looks too much like Pokémon's character?

Comment: To answer your questions, No, yes, and yes. IANAL, and you should consult with one.

Comment: You can get sued for anything. The more interesting question is if you would win a lawsuit *if* someone decides to sue you. And that depends not just on the legal situation but also on the skill of the lawyer you can afford.